# 404 error transferring wordpress website from local server

Tags: wordpress, installation, http-status-code-404

I've transferred my wordpress website from my localserver to a folder on my server. It is located in /wordpress. I have created a new database, new user and password and imported. I have also changed the location and home of the website in wp-options. I have changed the wp-config file. I'm still getting a 404 error. I then tried removing all the files, adding a clean install of wordpress then added my theme but still the same error. I can't even access admin or install. Can someone talk a look and tell me what I've done wrong? I have done this before and it normally works fine. Could it be the hosting?

[See website here](http://www.artling.com.au/wordpress/)

I've check my .htaccess file and it says the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you check for typo? Make sure the folder names are correctly pointed

Answer (score 0):

Check you're .htaccess file. I had this exact same issue the other day. Because it's in a subdirectory, it's keeping track of that in the .htaccess file, and I'm going to guess the subdirectory on the server is named differently than what it was on your development environment :)

Comment: Hmm it appears that I dont actually have .htaccess file. Is that normal?

Comment: If not then please create a blank one and upload it on your root detertory of wordpress.and make sure you have 755 permission on this file

Comment: Is there any other reason this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check you're .htaccess file and if you dont want to do coding in htaccess file.
Then login to wp-admin and go to the permalink section and hit update button
Hope it will solve the problem
Thanks

Comment: I can't login to wp-admin to change it. I have added a .htaccess file and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove .htaccess file and login in wordpress to run normally, lets check to conform this error due to .htaccess file.

Hope this helps you. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi there, I originally didn't have a .htaccess file. I added the file but nothing changed. I haven't been able to login to wordpress since I tried the transfer

Comment: Can you share with us root directory structure and theme  directory structure as screenshot?
Please make sure you transfer all files and folder. Thanks